# How to access the current context from an activity that is not foreground?

Tags: android, android-context

I'm having activity A listening for someone shaking the device. This can happen even when the user is on activity B. When the device is being shaken, I need to display a progress dialog and I so need the correct context. Like the shake function is in activity A, its appear that sometimes `this` keyword that I use for the context is not correct (as I guess its activity B as the correct context) and I get kind of window exception bad token...

I resume...
Activity B is foreground. User shakes the device. Activity A is reacting to the shake and want to display something but activity A is not currently foreground. Activity A that is using `this` keyword as the current context is sometimes crashing with window exception bad token. How can I get a correct and stable context ?

Answer (score 2):

You could save the context of Activity A in an Application class, which acts as a global singleton.

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {
   private static ApplicationController _appCtrl;
   private Context mActivityAContext;

   public static ApplicationController getAppCtrl()
   {
       return _appCtrl;
   }

   public void setContextForActivityA(Context context) 
   {
       mActivityAContext = context;
   }

   public Context getContextForActivityA()
   {
       return mActivityAContext;
   }

   public void onCreate() 
   {
       // Initialize the AppController class
       super.onCreate();
   ApplicationController._appCtrl = this;
   }

}
```

Now you could set the context for activity A in the setter Method and get it from everywhere in your app with:

```
ApplicationController.getContextForActivityA();
```

But be very careful with memory leaks when you pass an Activity context to other activities. See [link text](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350328/global-class-to-register-listeners-for-all-the-activities-in-android

Comment: That is a great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to save the context of an activity some where else as you might run into memory leaks during the application's life cycle. If you store the context in another class the Activity cannot be cleaned up by the Garbage Collector as the other class still holds a reference to its context.

You should think about making you shake recognition code somehow independent from you activity.

Comment: can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350328/global-class-to-register-listeners-for-all-the-activities-in-android