# Global class to register listeners for all the activities in android

Tags: java, android

I have two Activity classes. `Activity A` and `Activity B`. Later on I added `Activity C` which gets launched when user shakes the device being on `Activity A` or `Activity B`. Now if I register the ShakeListener in the `Activity A` and `Acitivity B`, I can achieve my goal

But what I want now, is a different thing, I do not want to change `Activity A` and `Activity B`. I want to write a different class, which runs for the whole app, and registers the ShakeListener for all the activities in the app. How can I do that? What kind of class should that be?

I tried extending BroadcastReceiver and registering the ShakeListener in the onReceive method, but used BOOT_EVENT which gets fired only when the device boots and not the starting of the application. So could not achieve my goal.

Then I was suggested by an SO user, to extend the Application class and registering the listener there. Now the listener gets registered, but now I need the currently running Activity and context to be passed to the `Activity C`. Here I'm back to zero again, because I don't want to add code in the Activity A or B. Also, AFAIK, the Application class is called before any of the Activity gets initiated, so is it possible to get the currently running Activity in the foreground?

Then I thought to move the code to find the activity in the Listener itself. Here also I needed to get the current activity and context. The context was the application context and then I tried to access all the currently open activities, [following this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131909/how-to-find-the-current-foreground-activity-in-android). Based on the version the code is a bit different. And this is not the recommended way and gives me error.

This is the class:

```
package com.something.someotherthing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;    
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by  Inquisitive on 20/5/15.
 */
public class ShakeEventListener implements SensorEventListener {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;


    private String[] getPreLollipop() {
        try {
               @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks =
                    activityManager().getRunningTasks(1);
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo currentTask = tasks.get(0);
            ComponentName currentActivity = currentTask.topActivity;
            return new String[]{currentActivity.getClassName()};
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("version","Exception" +e.getClass());
            String str[]= {"abc","def"};
            return str;
        }
    }

    private String[] getLollipop() {
        final int PROCESS_STATE_TOP = 2;

        try {
            Field processStateField = ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.class.getDeclaredField("processState");

            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes =
                    activityManager().getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
                if (
                    // Filters out most non-activity processes
                        process.importance <= ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND
                                &&
                                // Filters out processes that are just being
                                // _used_ by the process with the activity
                                process.importanceReasonCode == 0
                        ) {
                    int state = processStateField.getInt(process);

                    if (state == PROCESS_STATE_TOP)
                    /*
                    If multiple candidate processes can get here,
                            it's most likely that apps are being switched.
                    The first one provided by the OS seems to be
                    the one being switched to, so we stop here.
                            */
                        return process.pkgList;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return new String[] { };
    }

    private ActivityManager activityManager() {
        return (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }


    public String[] get() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            Log.d("Version","Pre-lollipop");
            for(String str:getPreLollipop())
                Log.d("Version",str);
            return getPreLollipop();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Version","Lollipop");
            for(String str:getLollipop())
                Log.d("Version",str);
            return getLollipop();
        }
    }
    public ShakeEventListener(Context context){
        Log.d("ACCELEROMETER","inside the constructor of shake event listener");
        this.context=context;
        String str[] = get();
        try {
            Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(str[0]);
            activity = (Activity) myClass.newInstance();
        }catch(Exception  e){
            //do something
        }

    }
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){

    }
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se){
        Log.d("SENSOR","On sensor changed");

      //need the activity and context here..
    }


}
```

When I try with a device having version below lollipop. It catches the SecurityException. With a device having version above lollipop, it gives the package name of my application, but not the particular class.

*1* what is the correct way to achieve my goal? Whatever approach I'm following is correct? in that case, I will try to debug the code to find activity

*2* If not, what are the other alternatives by which I can achieve my goal of having a global listener that listens from any activity within the app.

*3* Is it achievable at all, without changing the activities?

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using Service wit BroadcastReceiver and PendingIntent?

Comment: @Shahzeb I tried using Broadcast Receiver but used BOOT for the intent. I'm unaware of how to use it with PendingIntent. Can you suggest some good resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to implement a Service to listen to sensors in the background. Go through documentation:[Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

You cannot just use Broadcastreceiver to accomplish this task.

Reference:

[Android sensor listening when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093572/android-sensor-listening-when-app-in-background)

Refer this link for help:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-barometer-logger-acquiring-sensor-data--mobile-10558

Comment: I will have a look at the Service class. Though I don't want the sensor listening when app is in background, I want it listening only when the Activities A& B of the app  are in foreground to launch a different android activity, let say camera intent or something.

Comment: You can allow your service to run only when the app is running and stop the service when the application is stopped. Get familiar with it, it would be really helpful

Comment: nice link. would I be able to get the current running activity in the service class?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, Actually there are two types of services, Bound and Started. Bound is when you bind component with the service. You will learn this when you go through android documentation

Comment: Thanks, Can I bind the Service through Application and get current running Activity/Context  in the Service?

Comment: Check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm
Context is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Create a main activity class which will be extended by Activity A, B and C.
You can register your `ShakeListener` in this main activity.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. For extending also, I need to write a code in the Activity A, B and C, to extend from ShakeActivity? I do not have the change the Activities.

Comment: then how do I extend the ShakeActivity in ActivityA, B or C? where ShakeActivity is the Activity where I've registered the ShakeListener

Comment: when you extend a class from another, you add the parent's code to the child. If you have a ShakeActivity class with the sake related code and then you create a MainActivity extending shakeactivity, mainactivity has his own code and also shakeactivity code

Comment: @JesusS for this to work, I need to add this code in the MainActivity, MainActivity extends ShakeActivity. This is what I don't have to do. I dont want to alter MainActivity code

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own ActivityStack in Application class, properly manage by adding and removing activities. Finally refer to this stack from activity C.

There is example how ActivityStack works:
[Back Stack Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)